# .NET CMS to manage copy changes

Tags: content-management-system

We have web application that renders dynamic content. We want to manage our content copy changes via separate managed system where developer does not get involved in writing copy and just leave place holder and later on copy writer adds copy.

Per my knowledge, any CMS takes control most of front end and leaves developer to just do design and layout level control.

I am looking for some CMS that does not take control page structure but instead it runs as a thin layer before page rendering and replace the place holders with content.

To give an example, https://localizejs.com/ simply do localization with a JS on client, I can use that but I guess SEO will an issue since content is replaced with Javascript which most search engine won't execute.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called a **headless CMS**. That means it is a back-end interface for users to manage their content, but there is no front-end to render it - just APIs to access the content. You can call those APIs from your application.

A few examples I've used or looked at in the past:

- [Directus](http://getdirectus.com/)
- [Blackstar](https://blackstarcms.net/)

There's also a lot of momentum around using Drupal as a headless CMS.